# Hierarchy of the "extends" class

Tags: java, class, generics, extends

What is the hierarchy of extends? For example, things like Number, integer, and so on.

For example,

```
public class Foo<extends Integer>
{.....}
```

What types would this accept?

What is the highest type in the class?
What is the lowest type in the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to complete the generic declaration, then what you would have is a **upper-bounded generic type**.

```
 public class Foo<T extends Integer> { }
```

Here, `T` is bound to be anything that either *is* or *extends from* an `Integer`.  But, since `Integer` is a `final` class...it'd only be able to hold `Integer`.

So, a declaration like these are compile-time legal and enforced:

```
Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<>();
Foo bar = new Foo(); // This will produce raw type warnings!
```

...whereas a declaration like this isn't compile-time legal, since the bound is that it must either be or extend `Integer`.

```
Foo<Long> baz = new Foo<>();
```

Formally, the compiler will show you this:

> ```
>  Error:(17, 56) java: cannot infer type arguments for Foo<>;
>  reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Foo<T> conforms to Foo<java.lang.Long>
> ```

If you went higher in `Integer`'s hierarchy, you'd arrive at `Number`, which would allow you to instantiate with any class that extended `Number`:

```
public class Foo<T extends Number> { }
```

Then, the `Long` generic type would be legal, and your permissible types would be these:

- `Number`
- `Short`
- `Integer`
- `Double`
- `Float`
- `Byte`
- `BigDecimal`
- `BigInteger`

...just to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

It would accept anything that is the specified class, or a potential subclass of it.

So if I did:

```
<? extends MyClass>
```

It would allow types "MyClass", and say another class that was `public class Another extends MyClass`. But it wouldn't accept other classes.

Comment: Further information can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

```
public class Foo <T extends Integer>{.....}
```

?

`T` is going to accept anything that is-an `Integer`.

I don't understand what is the "highest" and "lowest" type you mean here.  However the above statement should be clear enough I believe.

e.g. You cannot pass in `Number` (which is the parent class of Integer).  You can pass in `Integer`.  If you have a `FooInteger` that extends `Integer`, you can use it here too.